# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12

I am getting this issue on xcode 12.4. It works fine on xcode 11.7. But whenever i tried to run the app, I get this. After some digging, I tried these steps:

```
Keychain Access -> Right-click on login -> Lock & unlock again -> Clean Xcode project ->Make build again

Deleting the derived data

Clean project and building again.

$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ pod install
```

None of them worked for me. These are the logs i am getting:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks 
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName- 
bnpxrpubbxscksgeymdgjgnkfkdn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectName.build/Debug- 
iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Script-2BDF9C2F03A1FC8AEBC5CB12.sh (in target 'ProjectName' from project 
'ProjectName')
cd /Users/user/Desktop/ABC\ Projects/ProjectName\ iPad
/bin/sh -c /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName- 
bnpxrpubbxscksgeymdgjgnkfkdn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectName.build/Debug- 
iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Script-2BDF9C2F03A1FC8AEBC5CB12.sh

mkdir -p /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName- 
bnpxrpubbxscksgeymdgjgnkfkdn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XYZ.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- 
.git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" 
"/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName- 
bnpxrpubbxscksgeymdgjgnkfkdn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.framework" 
"/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName- 
bnpxrpubbxscksgeymdgjgnkfkdn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XYZ.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
CryptoSwift.framework/
CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
CryptoSwift.framework/Info.plist

sent 774630 bytes received 70 bytes 1549400.00 bytes/sec
total size is 774294 speedup is 1.00
/Users/user/Desktop/ABC Projects/ProjectName iPad/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods- 
ProjectName-frameworks.sh: line 131: ARCHS[@]: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

These are the pods i am using:

```
pod 'p2.OAuth2', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.8.3'
```